# Finding complex eigenvalues and its corresponding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&6\\-15&-15\end{bmatrix}$$ has complex eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2} = a \pm bi$ where $a =$____ and $b = $ ____. The corresponding eigenvectors are $v_{1,2} = c \pm di$ where $c =$ (____ , _____ ) and $d =$ (____ , ___)

So I got the char. poly. eqn $\lambda^2 + 12\lambda + 45 = 0$

Then using the quad. eqn I got $-6 \pm 3i$ which I know is in the form $a \pm bi$ so I was thinking $a = -6$, $b = 3$, but instead they have $b = -3$ , **why?**

Also, I'm not sure how to obtain the corresponding eigenvectors because we are working with complex eigenvalues now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll cover the how to find the eigenvectors part.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&6\\-15&-15\end{bmatrix}$$

has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2} = -6\pm 3i$.

Now to find the associated eigenvectors, we find the nullspace of $$A-\lambda_{1,2}I = \begin{bmatrix}3-(-6\pm 3i)&6\\-15&-15-(-6\pm 3i)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}9\mp 3i & 6 \\ -15 & -9\mp 3i\end{bmatrix}$$

To find the nullspace I'll put this in REF:

$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}9\mp 3i & 6 \\ -15 & -9\mp 3i\end{bmatrix} &\sim \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 3\pm i \\ 3\mp i & 2\end{bmatrix} \\ &\sim \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 3\pm i \\ 0 & 2-(3\pm i)\frac{-(3\mp i)}{5}\end{bmatrix} \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 3\pm i \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Therefore all of the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_{1,2}$ are of the form $w_{1,2} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 15(-3\mp i)t \\ t\end{bmatrix}$.  Representative eigenvectors are then $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{v_{1,2} = \begin{bmatrix}-3\mp i \\ 5\end{bmatrix}}$$ which is obtained by setting $t=5$.

Comment: Why is your $\pm$ signed turned upside down? What's the significance

Comment: It means that $\lambda_1 = -6\oplus 3i$ corresponds to $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -3 \ominus i \\ 5\end{bmatrix}$, which I've circled the relevant signs.  Likewise $\lambda_2$ and $v_2$ have opposite signs in those places.

Comment: Somehow they are getting $(-1,1)$ and $(-1,2)$ I cant figure out how

Comment: Weird, maybe its an error

Comment: @Yusha Remember that there are an infinite number of vectors in the nullspace of $A-\lambda_{1,2}$.  I chose $t=5$ arbitrarily.  If you choose $t=1-2i$ you'll get your answer key's solution.  As to the reason your book arrived at the answer it did, I'll bet they didn't do the row swap that I did in the first step of my row reduction.  So both my and your answer key's solution are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\pm (-3)=\mp3=\pm3$. Hence, whether you use $b=3$ or $b=-3$ is irrelevant. To find the corresponding eigenvectors, you need to solve the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}3&6\\-15&-15\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\end{bmatrix}=\lambda_{1,2}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: I get stuck after I subtract the lambda value of 3 and I get $\begin{bmatrix}9-3i & 6\\-15 & -9-3i\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Should I put the matrix in RREF?

Comment: Because If I do $R_2 = 15R_1 + (9-3i)R_2$ this problem begans to get miserable as I will have a quadratic entry....

Comment: I even row reduced to get $\begin{bmatrix}9-3i&6\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and still I'm not getting the correct vectors. this has infinite solutions??

Answer (score 1):

The if $b=-3$, $a=-6$, we have $a \pm bi=-6 \pm 3i$, if $b=3, a=-6$ we still have $a\pm bi=-6 \pm 3i$, both answers are correct but if you're submitting into an online homework service like cengage-brain or webassign your professor may have just forgotten to include both cases as acceptable. To find eigenvectors, you need to solve $Av=\lambda v$, or, equivalently $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ (where I denotes the identity matrix. Why are these two systems equivalent?). Nothing really changes with the complex case so long as you know how to do arithmetic in $\mathbb{C}$. To get you started, for an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=-6+3i$, we set up:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A-\lambda I 
\end{bmatrix}
v=
\begin{bmatrix}
9-3i & 6 \\
-15 & -9-3i
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix} =0
$$
Giving the system:
$$ 
\begin{array}
 ((9-3i)v_1+6v_2=0 \\
-15v_1+(-9-3i)v_2=0
\end{array}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: $v_1 = -6v_2/(9-3i)$, $v_2 = 15v_1/(-9-3i)$?

Comment: I don't get it, don't i need to put the matrix in RREF form?

Comment: Because If I do $R_2 = 15R_1 + (9-3i)R_2$ this problem begans to get miserable as I will have a quadratic entry....

Comment: I even row reduced to get $\begin{bmatrix}9-3i&6\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and still I'm not getting the correct vectors. this has infinite solutions??

Comment: Yes, there will be infinitely many eigenvectors, but they will all be scalar multiples of one another, your first comment has you basically done, fix $v_1=1$ and solve for $v_2$ in terms of $v_1$, that will give you one eigenvector. Since matrix multiplication is linear, obvious any scalar multiple of this eigenvector will also be an eigenvector since $Av=\lambda v$ implies $A(cv)=c(Av)=c(\lambda v)=\lambda (cv)$.